# How do I run Half-Life 2 in 4k on a 1080p monitor?

Tags: half-life-2

I would like to play Half-Life 2 with my GeForce GTX 970 at 4k on a 1080p monitor. How would I do that? I have tried to adding custom resolutions in the NVIDIA control panel but I couldn't get 4k to work. I did get 1440p to work but it looked blurry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only applies to NVIDIA graphics cards like GTX 970 and higher.

> First open up the NVIDIA control panel and enable "DSR - Factors", Choose a DSR setting of your choice.
>   [image]

Next open up GeForce Experience, and select the game you want to enable DSR on, and click the wrench icon.
[image]

Select the available DSR resolution and click apply
[image]

GeForce Experience will now show the current resolution as a DSR resolution
[image]

Next confirm the resolution in game
[image]

[Source](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3587/~/how-to-enable-dynamic-super-resolution-in-games.)

Answer (score 3):

A 1080p monitor doesn't support 4K resolution.

Comment: I meant downscaling.

Comment: Yes, but there are options to downscale pre-rendered frames of bigger resolutions. Sometimes, that technique may result in better visuals.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2: ignore my answer, Chippie's one above is the best way to do this, if you have a GTX970 or higher.**

Some games (e.g. GTA5 using the 'Frame Scaling Mode' setting) have support for this (rendering at a higher resolution then downscaling to the native res of your monitor) but unfortunately HL2/Source engine games are not among them. **(Actually this can be done with an external program, see my edit below.)**

If you want to force a 4k resolution, your monitor would need to support resolution scaling when it receives a non-native res, and this doesn't always work properly for many resolutions, hence it looking blurry when forcing 1440p and not working with 4k at all.

**Edit**: I retract what I just said, it looks like it might be possible using a tool called GeDoSaTo. See this PCGamer article where someone got it running at 8k, it tells you how to do it.

http://www.pcgamer.com/half-life-2-8k-screenshot-gallery/

Comment: Chippies solution above is definitely the way to do it. I didn't know you can do this natively in the Nvidia control panel now. TIL.

Comment: GeDoSaTo is a good option for those who don't have a GTX970 or a higher tier GPU, due to the driver option missing in any lower tier gpu's. The performance might not be very good on a lower tier gpu though, unless it's done on an old game.